# How to count array items within a numeric range

Tags: c++

I am tasked with trying to create a histogram from a set of sample values that a user provides.  I've created the part of the program that creates the array from sample value input, but now I must take a user input for the histogram. They give min value, max value, and number of bins.  So, I'm assuming the number of bins specifies the size of the array for the histogram.  But I'm stumped as to how I go to my other array and count how many values are in the specified range for a particular bin. I hope this makes sense.  Here is my code for the program thus far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


#define MAX_SAMPLES 100
#define MAX_BINS 20
#define DOUBLE_TOLERANCE 0.0000005
#define EXIT_VALUE -999
int promptUserAndGetChoice(); //function prototype for the menu

//for information describing sample set of data and functions that operated on //those data
class SamplingClass 
   {  
      private:
         char charID; //the user enters an id for his sample set
         int numbOfValues; // the number of good values the user enters
         double sampleValues[MAX_SAMPLES]; //for the set of sample values. 
                                           //max is 100
      public:
         bool readFromKeyboard(); //prototype function 
         bool printToScreen();//protype function

      SamplingClass(); //constructor

   };

      SamplingClass::SamplingClass() //initializing charID
       {
        charID = 0;
       }

bool SamplingClass::readFromKeyboard()
   {
      int i = 0;
      cout << "Enter character identifier for this sample:";
      cin >> charID;
      cout << "you entered " <<charID << "\n";
      cout << "Enter all samples, then enter -999 to end:\n";

     while (i < MAX_SAMPLES)
      {
        cin >> sampleValues[i];     
   if 
      (sampleValues[i] < EXIT_VALUE + DOUBLE_TOLERANCE && sampleValues[i] > EXIT_VALUE - DOUBLE_TOLERANCE)
      {
         break;

      }//End if/else

        i++;

       }//End while

   numbOfValues = i;    
    return true;

   }

//this function checks whether charID is empty and then performs accordingly
bool SamplingClass::printToScreen() 
   {
   if (numbOfValues == 0) ///either make a test for existance first or charID

      {
         cout << "ERROR: Can not print uninitialized sampling!\n";
         return false;

      }  

   else 

      { 
         cout << "Data stored for sampling with identifier " << charID << ":\n"; 
         cout << "Total samples:" << numbOfValues << "\n";
         cout << "Samples (5 samples per line):\n";
         int i;

         for(i=0; i<numbOfValues;i++)
         {
         cout << sampleValues[i] << " ";

         if (((i+1) % 5) == 0)
          {  
             cout << endl;
          }

         }
         cout << endl;
        return true;

      }
    } 

class HistogramClass 
   {  
      private:
         double minBinValue; //specified by user
         double maxBinValue; // specified by user
         int numbBins; //specified by user, max of 10
         int histoBinCounts[MAX_BINS];

      public:
         bool setupHistogram(); //prototype function 
         bool addDataToHistogram(SamplingClass &sampling);//protype function
         bool printHistogramCounts();
         bool displayHistogram(); 
   };

bool HistogramClass::setupHistogram()
   {
      cout << "Enter minimum value:";
      cin >> minBinValue;
      cout << "Enter maximum value:";
      cin >> maxBinValue;
      cout << "Enter number of bins:";
      cin >> numbBins;
      cout << "\n";
      if (numbBins <= MAX_BINS) 
         {cin >> numbBins;}
      else
        cout << "Sorry, the maximum amount of bins allowed is 20. Try again!\n";

    }



//function for the menu options that display to user  
int promptUserAndGetChoice()

   {
     cout << "1. Enter a sample set of data values\n";
     cout << "2. Print the contents of the current sample set\n";
     cout << "3. Reset / Provide values for setting up a histogram\n";
     cout << "4. Add the contents of current sample set to histogram\n";
     cout << "5. Print bin counts contained in histogram\n";
     cout << "6. View the histogram in graphical form\n";
     cout << "0: Exit the program\n\n";
   }

int main()

{  
   const int enter_option = 1;
   const int printContents_option = 2;
   const int reset_option = 3;
   const int add_option = 4;
   const int printBin_option = 5;
   const int viewHist_option = 6;
   const int exit_option = 7;
   int menuChoice;
   SamplingClass sampleSet;
   HistogramClass histoSet;

   do 
      {
        promptUserAndGetChoice();
        cout << "Your Choice: ";
        cin >> menuChoice;

   if (menuChoice == 1)
      {
       sampleSet.readFromKeyboard();
       cout << "Last Operation Successful: YES\n\n";
      }
   else if (menuChoice == 2)

      {
      sampleSet.printToScreen();
      }

   else if (menuChoice == 3)
      {
      histoSet.setupHistogram();
      }

    } 
     while (menuChoice != 7);
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each bin in a histograms is typically the same size. So when the user gives you the min, max and number of bins, you can compute the size, and therefore the range, of each bin. Each bin will be of size

```
bin_size = (max-min)/#_of_bins.
```

Now to figure out which bin a value goes into, compute

```
bin = ceil(value/bin_size)
```

(Or take the floor if you start numbering your bins at 0). And increment the count in this bin. Once you do this for all values, you can print out the count in each bin and this is your histogram.

Update: If min != 0, then the formula is:

```
bin = (int) (value-min)/bin_size
```

Using the cast here b/c codemesserupper can't use libs. bin here will be 0-indexed.

Comment: What's ceil? Is that a new variable?

Comment: @codemesserupper: It's a function in `<math.h>` or `<cmath>` that takes the smallest integer above or equal to its argument.  The `floor` function does the opposite: the largest integer below or equal to the argument.

Comment: Ah, ok that's a problem in that I'm not allowed to rely on libraries for this. :(

Comment: I think you can still get away without using math.h by casting the float to an int. int bin = (int) value/bin_size. This will do the same thing as the floor function by setting bin equal to the number in front of the decimal point.

Comment: @Girish: your `bin =` formula above doesn't account for the possibility that value isn't 0 based (i.e. min != 0).  For example, say you had 10 bins for values from 50 to 100.  A value of 99 should be in the 10th bin, but your formula of value / bin_size gives 99 / 5 = 19.

Comment: My approach would still work. I'll update my answer but I would subtract min from value and dividing that by bin_size, and taking the floor of that. So, in your example, 99-50=49. Then 49/5=9.8, the floor of which is 9. When using floor, bin numbering starts at 0. QED.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the min and max, then any particular value x should be considered to fall into the array at index:

```
 (x - min) / (max - min) * #bins
```

This will span the range 0..#bins inclusive, so just round down from #bins to #bins-1 when necessary.

EDIT: to be more explicit, and ignoring the object boundaries, the basic approach is to 0 the histoBinCounts then:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbOfValues; ++i)
{
    double x = sampleValues[i];
    int bin = (x - minBinValue) / (maxBinValue - minBinValue) * numbBins;
    if (bin >= 0 && bin < numbBins)
        ++histoBinCounts[bin];
}
```

Comment: Hmmm--I'm not sure I follow. The sampling set array has already been created by the time the user enters in min, max and number of bins. sorry, I'm a total newbie, so I don't even know if I'm asking the right questions.  By the way, thanks so much for the quick response! I think I am creating a new array of size bins that the user enters. Then in each slot of the array goes a count of the number of things in the first array that fall in the range of each new bin slot. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, I'm going to work with this and let you know how it goes.  THanks to everyone!